# Empirial evidence that standing 1.5-2m apart reduces risk of airborne contagion

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology, airborne-transmission

One of the measures proposed by the Dutch government to minimise the risk of spreading/acquiring the Covid-19 virus is [keeping a distance of 1.5 meters](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/actueel/nieuws/2020/03/16/wat-betekent-afstand-houden-vanwege-het-coronavirus) from other people.
Similar advice is given in other countries, see [this related question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/is-standing-apart-2m-an-appropriate-social-distancing-measure-for-choirs).

I understand the mechanism: infected people spread droplets when they sneeze, cough or even speak, these droplets contain enough virus to infect a person that inhales a droplet or maybe rubs it in their eyes or mouth when they touch their face.

But is there any **empirical** evidence that standing 1.5 meters apart significantly reduces infection risk for airborne diseases? It does not have to be evidence on Covid-19 per se, the flu or the common cold would suffice.

Comment: There's a difference between "airborne" and "droplet". COVID-19 is primarily transmitted by respiratory droplets, which don't travel much more than 2 meters: they're big, heavy, and fall quickly. Measles, by contrast, is airborne: it travels in tiny particles which can go far and hang in the air for hours.

Comment: Thank you harles, i did not know about the difference. But so very little is known about Covid-19, do we know for sure it is not airborne?

Comment: Out of droplet, airborne, and fecal-oral, airborne seems to be the least important transmission mode for COVID-19. Some (e.g., Paul Offit) argue that fecal-oral is the primary mode of transmission; most believe that it is respiratory droplet. It's widely believed that airborne transmission is possible, but no one thinks it's a major source of infection, and some think ir doesn't happen at all.

Comment: @Charles:  see [ https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMc2004973 ] for stability of COVID-19 in aerosol

Comment: @BobE Thank you, very interesting! I don't have any explanation that would reconcile the empirical finding with the experimental data, but I'm sure it's been studied.